# NodeJS: read JSON and save result to variables

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am trying to make a little website with NodeJS and I am using JSON from http://www.mywebsite.com/json

That JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "response:" {
        name: "John",
        age: 29,         
    }

}
```

And my **app.js** looks like this (without require, app.set etc..)

```
app.route('/add')
    .get(function(req, res) {
        var url = "http://www.mywebsite.com/json";
        var name;
        var age;

        request({
            url: url,
            json: true
        }, function(err, res, data) {
            if(!err) {
                name = data.response.name;
                age = data.response.age;
            }
    });    

        res.render('add', { name:name, age:age });
    })
```

Why my **name** and **age** variables are both undefined? I was looking similar problems and someone said that request method is asynchronous and I am trying to synchronously return result, is that right? How I can synchronously return result and save it to variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always remember the fact that a request is asynchronous, you have to wait until the request is completed to render the page. One way of doing it is rendering the page in the callback of the request :

```
app.route('/add')
    .get(function(req, res) {
    var url = "http://www.mywebsite.com/json";
    var name;
    var age;

    request({
        url: url,
        json: true
    }, function(err, res, data) {
        if(!err) {
            name = data.response.name;
            age = data.response.age;
        }
        res.render('add', { name:name, age:age });
    });    

})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try for this:

```
request({
            url: url,
            json: true
        }, function(err, res, data) {
            if(!err) {
                name = data.response.name;
                age = data.response.age;
               res.render('add', { name:name, age:age });
            }
});
```